# PHP APC cannot increase cache above 32m

Tags: linux, php, debian, alternative-php-cache

apc.shm_size I set it to 128M I have also try 128 (without M)

But It always 32M :(

/proc/sys/kernal/shmmax is set to 134217728

Comment: What web server are you using ? PHP-FPM ? NGINX ? APACHE ?